# Rails 5 get specific field/value from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called group.  I want this method to return just the content of the relevant record's ID field.  At the moment it returns an active record object ID.

```
def get_group_name(group_id)
    Group.select([:name]).where("id = ?", group_id)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you using this method? Seems like something you'd like to use in a view... so I'm wondering whether the issue you are trying to solve, should be solved by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do easier with find

```
def get_group_name(group_id)
  Group.find(group_id).name
end
```

Comment: Just know that this will select the whole group row from the database and throw it away to only keep the name, which is a lot of extra overhead for just one field. There’s no good reason to do this approach as you’d be better off just having an association called `group` that’s cached by ActiveRecord. Take a look at my answer, which explains how to only select the group’s name from the database, and the pitfalls that can come with that. Also, ActiveRecord objects are slow to create in memory compared to plucking the field directly.

Answer (score -1):

This will get you only the name of the group.

```
def get_group_name(group_id)
  Group.where(id: group_id).limit(1).pluck(:name).first
end
```

It will run this query:

```
SELECT name
  FROM groups
 WHERE id = ?
 LIMIT 1;
```

A side note is, be careful of what you’re doing. Any time you have a method to get a single field’s value, while it can be more efficient at times, it can easily be misused. If you’re looping over a collection of group ids trying to grab all of the names, then you’d be better off 1 query up front for all of the names as opposed to 1 per group id on the page. So just keep and eye on your console and pay attention to the queries you’re running.

Also, if you are looking over a collection, you may want to look into `includes` for your ActiveRecord queries, to include the group data in the previous query. You can benchmark this all to figure out what’s fastest for your use case.